# how to insert imagepath in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table named `employee` with the following columns:

```
empid int (autoincrement,PK), 
empname varchar,
imagepath varchar
```

I want to insert `empid`, `empname`, and `imagepath` where image name should be the value of auto-increment id like `~/images/1.jpg` (here 1 is auto-incremented id of that row)

this is perfect code or not ???

```
insert into employee (name, path) 
values
(
 'sarju',
 (select '~/images/'+Cast(ISNULL(max(empid),0)+1 as varchar(50))+'.jpg' from emp)
)
```

Comment: You could write a trigger to do what you want.

Comment: thanks but can u provide an example ? ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a perfect code because MAX(ID)+1 can be different from next Auto increment value. You can use IDENT_CURRENT function

```
INSERT INTO employee (name,path) 
SELECT 'sarju','~/images/'+CAST(IDENT_CURRENT('employee') AS VARCHAR(50))+'.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

insert into employee (name,path) values('sarju',(select '~/images/'+Cast(ISNULL(max(empid),0)+1 as varchar(50))+'.jpg' from emp))

yes, this is possible

Answer (score 1):

I may get dinged for this because a lot of people don't like triggers, but this is a perfect example of what they were built for (and I honestly want the world to know that):

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_imagepath ON dbo.employee FOR insert AS

UPDATE employee
SET imagepath = '~/images/' + CAST((SELECT empid FROM inserted) AS VARCHAR) + '.jpg'
WHERE empid = (SELECT empid FROM inserted)
```

they do serve a purpose, and things like this are exactly that. See, you just need to `INSERT` the name of the employee and the `TRIGGER` will run automatically. This is honestly the most straight forward way of handling this. The other benefit of this - if you bulk inserted a bunch of employees or ran insert statements from Management Studio, the trigger still runs! You don't need to dig up that crazy `INSERT` statement!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** While this work, I have to say that Nenad Zivkovics solution is better.

You could use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the latest created ID. That would also be safer so that you dont get the wrong ID.

```
insert into employee (name) 
values ( 'sarju')

declare @employeeId as int = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

update employee set 
path = '~/images/' + cast(@employeeId as varchar(50)) + '.jpg' 
where empid = @employeeId
```

Comment: can i insert record using one query??

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one specific folder where will be stored your images, you can just make your field `imagepath` as computed

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
(
    empid int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    empname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    imagepath AS ('~/images/'+cast(empid AS VARCHAR(50))+'.jpg')
)

INSERT INTO employee (empname) 
VALUES ('sarju')
INSERT INTO employee (empname) 
VALUES ('sarju2')
```

Comment: in case insert differrent value in imagepath column then ??

Comment: suppose i insert like '~/images/' only then what??

Comment: not, sure that I understand you:)
you not need to insert `imagepath`, it will be computed automaticle based on `empid`. You just insert your `empname`, next `empid` will be auto-incremented (let's say to 10) and `imagepath` computed to `'~/images/10.jpg'`

Comment: yes i understand you , but in case in imagefield to insert '~/images/10.jpg' or only '10.jpg' in insert qry so ...??

Comment: `imagepath` will contain `'~/images/10.jpg'` and your insert statement will be just `INSERT INTO employee (empname) VALUES ('sarju')`, it means you not need to insert `imagepath` and worry about it

Comment: you r right but '~/images/' it is not fix, it can be any folder like '~/img/'

Comment: got it - you have different paths in one time, so it's means that this way not for you and I think using of the `IDENT_CURRENT` will be the best way (see answer from @Michael Perrenoud)